# How to Equalize 2 columns I & Q data of the 16 QAM constellation?

Tags: matlab

I need help regarding the I & Q data which I extracted from VPI simulation software. The data is for 16 QAM constellation which is distorted by chromatic dispersion. The data is in 2 columns and have 512 rows. I loaded my Tx and distorted Rx data extracted from VPI simulation software in to LMS equalizer code. And run the algorithm while changing the step size. I got some better constellation points but the equalizer is not converging. I thought maybe the data in 2 columns is the problem. My basic question is how can I equalize this type of data? Maybe some other Matlab algorithm is required to fix it but I am not confirmed.
How can I equalize this data so that I have clean constellation after equalization?

Comment: Well, you write an equalizer. Can you try to narrow down to a single, clear signal processing question? In your last question, Dan explained that you need to put as much relevant information as you have in your question. I'm afraid you haven't done this here – what have you tried, why is the LMS equalizer from last question not working, where exactly are you stuck, what is the metric under which you'll evaluate success of your equalization...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is that yes I worked with LMS equalization. I loaded my Tx and distorted Rx data in to LMS equalizer code. And run the algorithm while changing the step size. I got some better constellation points but the equalizer is not converging.  I thought maybe the data in 2 columns is the problem. My basic question is how can I equalize this type of data? Maybe some other Matlab algorithm.

Comment: Again, this is all info that should be part of the question, not something you discuss in the comments when people that know the comments to your other questions bring it up. Please explain way more in the question. You *know* stuff, and telling us *what* you know helps us give better answers! We're also not offering matlab code written to your specification (that's explicitly off-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question. Also in my previous comment I am not asking for the Matlab code. I am discussing my question if I am doing the right thing.